# Average query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with this four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE team (  
      id    CHAR(3),  
      name     VARCHAR2(80) CONSTRAINT nn_team_name     NOT NULL,  
      district VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT nn_team_district NOT NULL,  

CONSTRAINT pk_team  
PRIMARY KEY (id)  
);  

 CREATE TABLE game (  
     home,        
     away,  
     round    NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT nn_game_round NOT NULL,  
     spectators NUMBER(5),  
--  
 CONSTRAINT pk_game  
      PRIMARY KEY (home, away),  
--  
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_home  
      FOREIGN KEY (home)  
      REFERENCES team(id),  
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_away  
      FOREIGN KEY (away)  
      REFERENCES team(id),  
--
 CONSTRAINT ck_game_round  
     CHECK (round BETWEEN 1 AND 30),  
 CONSTRAINT ck_game_spectators
    CHECK (spectators > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE player (  
     nickname        NUMBER(8),  
     name       VARCHAR2(80) CONSTRAINT nn_player_name      NOT NULL,  
     yearOfBirth NUMBER(4)    CONSTRAINT nn_player_yearOfBirth NOT NULL,   
     team                  CONSTRAINT nn_player_team    NOT NULL,  
--
CONSTRAINT pk_player  
    PRIMARY KEY (nickname),  
--
CONSTRAINT fk_player_team  
    FOREIGN KEY (team)  
    REFERENCES team(id),  
--
CONSTRAINT ck_player_yearOfBirth  
    CHECK (yearOfBirth BETWEEN 1950 AND 2000)  
);

CREATE TABLE plays (  
    player,  
    home,         
    away,    
    goals      NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT nn_plays_goals NOT NULL,  
--
CONSTRAINT pk_plays  
    PRIMARY KEY (player, home, away),  
--
CONSTRAINT fk_plays_player  
     FOREIGN KEY (player) REFERENCES player(nickname),  
CONSTRAINT fk_plays_game  
     FOREIGN KEY (home, away) REFERENCES game(home, away),  
--
CONSTRAINT ck_plays_goals   
     CHECK (goals >= 0)
```

);

and i'm having trouble with this four queries:

- Average number of goals per game per round. The result should be ordered by round number.
- Names and nicknames of the players, and their team id's, that played away in less than five games. The result should include the players that didn't played in any game. There must be ONLY one SELECT clause.
- id's of the teams with the larger number of goals against per round. In case there's more than one team with the larger number of goals against, both teams should show in the result. Assume the teams play in every round.
- Nicknames and id's of their clubs,for the players that scored the larger number of goals in two, and only two games. If there are more than one player in this conditions, none is shown.

Could you guys help me out ? Because i've managed to do more simple queries, but i got stuck in this ones...

Comment: SQL*PLUS is an oracle thing, not a MySQL thing.

Comment: @OllieJones sorry, i've updated it!

Comment: Do you have any test data? Can you post an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested as I haven't got any test data...

**Query 1**

```
--    Average number of goals per game per round.
--    The result should be ordered by round number.
WITH num_games AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_games,
         round
  FROM   game
  GROUP BY round
)
SELECT g.round,
       SUM( p.goals / n.num_games )
         AS avg_goals_per_game_per_round
FROM   game g
       INNER JOIN
       plays p
       ON ( g.home = p.home AND g.away = p.away )
       INNER JOIN
       num_games n
       ON ( g.round = n.round )
GROUP BY g.round
ORDER BY g.round;
```

**Query 2**

```
--    Names and nicknames of the players, and their team id's,
--    that played away in less than five games.
--    The result should include the players that didn't played in any game.
--    There must be ONLY one SELECT clause.
SELECT p.nickname,
       p.name,
       p.team
FROM   player p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       plays l
       ON ( p.nickname = l.player )
GROUP BY p.nickname, p.name, p.team
HAVING COUNT( 1 ) < 5;
```

**Query 3**

```
--    id's of the teams with the larger number of goals against per round.
--    In case there's more than one team with the larger number
--    of goals against, both teams should show in the result.
--    Assume the teams play in every round.
WITH player_home_or_away_goals AS (
  SELECT player,
         home,
         away,
         goals,
         CASE WHEN home = (SELECT team
                           FROM   player p
                           WHERE  p.nickname = l.player)
              THEN 'H'
              ELSE 'A'
              END AS home_away
  FROM   plays l
),
game_home_or_away_goals AS (
  SELECT home,
         away,
         SUM( DECODE( home_away, 'H', goals, null ) ) AS home_goals,
         SUM( DECODE( home_away, 'A', goals, null ) ) AS away_goals
  FROM   player_home_or_away_goals
  GROUP BY home, away
),
team_goals_per_game_per_round AS (
  SELECT g.home AS team_id,
         h.home_goals AS goals_for,
         h.away_goals AS goals_against,
         g.round
  FROM   game g
         INNER JOIN
         game_home_or_away_goals h
         ON ( g.home = h.home AND g.away = h.away )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT g.away AS team_id,
         h.away_goals AS goals_for,
         h.home_goals AS goals_against,
         g.round
  FROM   game g
         INNER JOIN
         game_home_or_away_goals h
         ON ( g.home = h.home AND g.away = h.away )
),
total_team_goals_per_round AS (
  SELECT team_id,
         round,
         SUM( goals_for )     AS total_goals_for_per_round,
         SUM( goals_against ) AS total_goals_against_per_round
  FROM   team_goals_per_game_per_round
  GROUP BY team_id,
           round
),
max_goals_against_per_round AS (
  SELECT round,
         MAX( total_goals_against_per_round ) AS greatest_goals_against
  FROM   total_team_goals_per_round
  GROUP BY round
)
SELECT t.team_id,
       t.round
FROM   total_team_goals_per_round t
       INNER JOIN
       max_goals_against_per_round m
       ON (    t.round = m.round
           AND t.total_goals_against_per_round = m.greatest_goals_against );
```

**Query 4**

```
--    Nicknames and id's of their clubs, for the players that scored
--    the larger number of goals in two, and only two games. If there
--    are more than one player in this conditions, none is shown.
```

Please post some test data and the desired output as it is unclear exactly what the requirement is for this question.

- Do you want the subset of players who only played two games and then to find the highest scoring player from that subset?
- Or, do you want the player with the highest score in exactly two games regardless of how many games they have played in total?
- Or, is it something else?

Comment: In what way is it confusing or not simple? Query 2 is about as simple as it can get. Query 1 may have another solution but I can't immediately think of it.

Comment: how do i send some test data ?

Comment: i want the player with the highest score in exactly two games regardless of how many games they have played in total

Comment: your third query looks really confusing, can you try to make a little more simple ? or explain what's going on ?